# Can one integrate an exponential in a polynomial without expanding the polynomial?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am trying to solve a problem related to failure rates where multiple failures can occur, assuming a Poisson process for failures following an exponential distribution. I am trying to build a theoretical model to validate simulations. I have gotten to the point where I am pretty sure that between $t=0$ and $t=T$, the expected time the system is in a state with $m$ failures is
$$
\int_0^T \exp\left(-\frac{nt}{\tau}\right)\left[1 - \exp\left(-\frac{t}{\tau}\right)\right]^m,
$$
where the first exponential is the survival function of $n$ points of failure and (i.e., $s(t)^n$) and the second part is the cumulative distribution of failures, i.e. $F(t)^m=[1-s(t)]^m$.

I would like to solve this for multiple cases and am wondering whether there is a more elegant way to solve it than
$$
\int_0^T\exp\left(-\frac{nt}{\tau}\right)\sum_{k=0}^m{m \choose k}(-1)^k\exp\left(-\frac{kt}{\tau}\right)dt=\left[\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{k+1}{m \choose k}\frac{\tau}{n+k}\exp\left(-\frac{(n+k)t}{\tau}\right)\right]_0^T
$$

Comment: With the substitution $u = \exp(-t/\tau)$, it seems related to an incomplete beta function.

Comment: Thanks, I'll explore that.